# Xamarin Android customs states not working after upgrading to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to update my Xamarin.Android project to target Android 10 and Visual Studio 2019 but there is a bug that i can not solve.

I have custom states for some components, but their condition is being ignored and always shows "true" except when other default state in android is active and upper in the hierarchy. This is the code example:

Attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="CustomStates">
    <attr name="state_error" format="boolean"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

CustomButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/XXXX.XXXX.XXXX">

  <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/DisabledButton"/>    

  <item app:state_error="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ErrorButton"/>  

  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/PressedButton"/>

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/DefaultButton"/>

</selector>
```

CustomButton.cs

```
public class CustomButton : ImageButton
{
    private static int[] errorState = { Resource.Attribute.state_error };
    private bool error;

    ...

    public bool Error
    {
        get
        {
            return this.error;
        }

        set
        {
            this.error = value;
            this.RefreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    public override int[] OnCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)
    {
        int[] state = base.OnCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);

        if (this.error)
        {                
            LoginButton.MergeDrawableStates(state, errorState);
        }

        return state;
    }
}
```

My app is always showing @drawable/ErrorButton even when the property Error is setted to false. The only case when @drawable/ErrorButton is not being showed, is when the button is disabled (correctly shows @drawable/DisabledButton).

This is not happening in Visual Studio 2017 targeting Android 9. I am doing the test in the same devices (Android 5.1 and Android 7.1).

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! It's strange , if you can share the sample project link here , I will check it in local site .  By the way , if be sure it's an issue , you also can submit [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues) to follow it .